# Is an O(|E|+|V|) algorithm considered O(|E|)?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

When I am asked to design an O(|E|)algorithm, is it acceptable to design a O(|E|+|V|)algorithm and call it O(|E|)? (If the graph is connected)

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:**
`O(|E|)` refers to that each edge should be only traversed (processed) a constant number of times (on average), so yes, you are supposed to also process vertices with `O(|E|+|V|)` complexity.

**A bit longer answer:**
The question you need to ask yourself is:

If I double the amount of edges (for large edge numbers), will the algorithm take approximately twice as long to execute. If the answer is **yes**, then your complexity is `O(|E|)`.

Finally keep in mind that in a connected graph, the maximum amount of `|V|` is `|E|+1` because `|E|>=|V|-1`. Therefore in worse case scenario `O(|E|+|V|)` is `O(2|E|+1)` = `O(|E|)`

Comment: The maximum amount of `|V|` is `|E|+1`, not `|E|-1`. This doesn't change the rest of the answer.

Comment: @Kostas Why did you undo my edit?! In a connected graph, `|E|>=|V|-1` which implies `|V| <= |E|+1`. The answer you edited is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is connected, the number of edges (i.e |E|) is at least one less than the number of vertices (i.e. |E| >= |V|-1). Therefore, |E|+|V| = O(|E|+|E|+1) = O(|E|). So if your algorithm is O(|E|) it is also O(|E|+|V|).